trying to draw an ellipse using css
I have this ellips that  I have to draw in css, but I can't make sense of it anyone has an idea how can I do it ? knowing that I have to make it responsive
I tries to make it first as an svg but it was too big , then I tried to look for a way to draw it using css but  can't put my hand on the right track

For example see ellipse()

Drawing an ellipse in CSS can be a bit tricky, especially if you want it to be responsive. One way to achieve this is by using CSS border-radius. While border-radius is typically used for creating rounded corners, it can also be used to create elliptical shapes by specifying different horizontal and vertical radii.



@VladimirPetukhov Looks like this could be an answer

Based on Vladimir Petukhov's comment, here it is:


<style>
  .ellipse {
    width: 80%;
    /* Adjust the width as needed */
    height: 100vw;
    /* Adjust the height relative to width for responsiveness */
    background-color: #212D49;
    /* Background color of the ellipse*/
    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    /* 50% for horizontal radius, 50% for vertical radius */
    margin: 20px auto;
    /* Center the ellipse horizontally and add some margin */
  }
</style>
<div class="ellipse"></div>



With your SVG, simplified:


<svg viewBox="0 0 869 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<ellipse cx="434.5" cy="512" rx="434.5" ry="512" fill="#212D49" />
</svg>



Notice that the cx and the rx must be the half of the viewbox's width, and the cy and the ry the half of the viewbox's height!

I was looking for something like this  but I don't know where to start from to add it in a website in a responsive way I tried to use the SVG file that I got but its format is too big and couldn't find how to make it responsive code <svg width="869" height="1024" viewBox="0 0 869 1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M308.5 727C107.833 777.903 985.339 1083 855 1083C724.661 1083 -21 1154.58 -21 1027C-21 899.422 -190.675 -21.5237 39 -67.5001C1148 -289.5 683 632 308.5 727Z" fill="#212D49"/> </svg>

I've updated my answer with your SVG data, simplified. Please, take a look.

Using border-radius:
<div class="ellipse"></div>

.ellipse {
  width: 200px; /* Adjust width as needed */
  height: 100px; /* Adjust height as needed */
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50% 100%; /* Horizontal radius, Vertical radius */
}

Using the shape-outside property :
<div class="ellipse"></div>

.ellipse {
  width: 200px; /* Adjust width as needed */
  height: 100px; /* Adjust height as needed */
  background-color: #ccc;
  shape-outside: ellipse(200px 100px); /* Horizontal radius, Vertical radius */
}

